# Python3, split dataset with even distribution, without shuffling

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, split

I have two datasets: X and y. I want to split them into training set and testing set. And I want to keep the sequence of their data (no random shuffle). Take the following codes for example. The X has 10 rows (y is the same). The result I want is that X_train has about 2/3 of the total rows and x_test has about 1/3 of the total rows. And most importantly, X_train should not just be from 0 to 6 rows, but should pick rows as evenly as possible from 0 to 9. Same applies to X_test.

```
import numpy as np
X = np.arange(50).reshape(10,5)
y = np.arange(10)

test_size = 0.33
n_total = X.shape[0]  # total number of rows
n_train = int(test_size*n_total)

# The following is bad example, since X_train picks rows from 0 to 6.
X_train, X_test = X[:n_train], X_test[n_train:]

# Wanted result: X_train and X_test are distributed across the total rows, as evenly as possible.
X_train = X[0], X[2], X[3], X[4], X[6], X[7], X[8]
X_test = X[1], X[5], X[9]
```

Can you please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make a permutation of 10 and use that as your indices and pick the first n for train and the rest for test. Technically you have not shuffled the data but you have shuffled the indices. Hopefully that solves your problem.

```
np.random.permutation(10)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But it does not solve my problem completely. I also want the test dataset evenly distributed. In your suggestion I may get `[6, 8, 7, 0, 4, 9, 1, 5, 2, 3]`. Then, if I choose the last three elements be my test set, `[5, 2, 3]`. These three values are all between 0 and 5, not evenly distributed. One ideal result would be `[1, 5, 9]`.

Answer (score 0):

The required train and test splits can be obtained by using sorted lists containing randomly sampled indices, where the length of the lists will be equal to the required split sizes. Below code implements the above solution for your required result.

```
import numpy as np
from random import sample

y         = np.arange(10)
len_y     = y.shape[0]

'''Indices of test split
'''
test_size = round(0.33*len_y)                 % as you required 1/3 percent test split
ind_test  = sample(range(len_y), test_size)   % randomly sampled indices
ind_test.sort()                               % sorted list of randomly sampled indices

'''Indices of train split
'''
ind_train = list(set(range(len_y)) - set(ind_test))     % set of all indices - set of test indices

'''Required splits
'''
y_train = y[ind_train]
y_test  = y[ind_test]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It does not fully solve my problem. I want the test samples to be as evenly distributed as possible. That means, if to pick 3 test samples out of 10, it is better be something like one in [0, 1, 2, 3], one in [4, 5, 6], and one in [7, 8, 9].